# How to get weighted sum depending on multipliers in column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have the table in Excel:

[image]

In column `C` (**Sum**) I want to get sum this way:

- If in column `A` or `B` value is **1** then take `Amount` **48** and multiply by `Multiplier (1)` = **2**.
- If in column `A` or `B` value is **0** then take `Amount` **48** and multiply by `Multiplier (0)` = **1,5**.
- Then **K1** and **K2** summed.

---

So for **row 2** the result in column `C` will be: **48*2 + 48*2** = **192**.
For **row 5** the result in column `C` will be: **48*1,5 + 48*2** = **168**.

---

Is it possible to automate this process using Excel formula for **C** column (inspite of number of columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could use Countif (no shorter though)

```
=COUNTIF(A2:D2,0)*I$2*I$1+COUNTIF(A2:D2,1)*I$3*I$1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when entering (since it's an array formula)

[image]

EDIT: I'm not great with formulas, so there is I'm sure a shorter alernative...