# How to get weighted sum depending on two conditions in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, worksheet-function, multiple-conditions

I have this table in **Excel**:
[image]

I am trying to get weighted sum depending on two conditions:

- Whether it is **Company 1** or **Company 2** (shares quantity differ)
- Whether `column A` (**Company 1**) and `column B` (**Company 2**) has **0** or **1** (multipliers differ)

---

**Example:**
Lets calculate weighted sum for **row 2**:

**Sum** = **2** (*multiplier 1*) * **50** (*1 share price*) * **3** (*shares quantity for `Company 1`*) +

+**0.5** (*multiplier 0*) * **50** (*1 share price*) * **6** (*shares quantity for `Company 2`*) = **450**

So, **Sum** for **Row 2** = **450**.

---

For now I am checking only for multipliers (**1** or **0**) using this code:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:B2,0)*$B$9*$B$8 + COUNTIF(A2:B2,1)*$B$9*$B$7
```

But it does not take into account the shares quantities for **Company 1** or **Company 2**. I only multiply **1 share price** with multipliers, but not with shares quantity).

---

How can I also check whether it is **Company 1** or **Company 2** in order to multiply by corresponding **Shares quantity**?

---

**Upd:**

**Rasmus0607** gave a solution when there are only two companies:

```
=$B$9*$E$8*IF(A2=1;$B$7;$B$8)+$B$9*$E$9*IF(B2=1;$B$7;$B$8)
```

**Tom Sharpe** gave a more general solution (number of companies can be greater than 2)

---

*I uploaded my Excel file to DropBox:*
[*Excel file*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f2re3cos4e2u24d/stackover.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: I answered the original question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012741/how-to-get-weighted-sum-depending-on-multipliers-in-column-in-excel/40016116#40016116 and suggested the Countif's. The point here was that there could be more than 2 companies but they had the same weighting. I'm wondering if this new post actually will need an answer that can be extended to more than two companies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer a more general way of doing it with the benefit of hindsight that you can apply to more than two columns by altering the second CHOOSE statement:-

```
=SUM(CHOOSE(2-A2:B2,$B$7,$B$8)*CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:B),$E$8,$E$9))*$B$9
```

Unfortunately it's an array formula that you have to enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>. But it's a moot point whether or not it would be better just to use one of the other answers with some repetition and keep it simple.

You could also try this:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET($B$6,2-A2:B2,0)),N(OFFSET($E$7,COLUMN(A:B),0)))*$B$9
```

[image]

Here's how it would be for three companies

```
=SUM(CHOOSE(2-A2:C2,$B$7,$B$8)*CHOOSE(COLUMN(A:C),$F$8,$F$9,$F$10))*$B$9
```

(array formula) or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET($B$6,2-A2:C2,0)),N(OFFSET($F$7,COLUMN(A:C),0)))*$B$9
```

Answer (score 2):

=$B$9*$E$8*IF(A2=1;$B$7;$B$8)+$B$9*$E$9*IF(B2=1;$B$7;$B$8)

Answer (score 1):

Since in the `COUNTIF` function, you don't know beforehand, which company column contains a 0, or a 1, I would suggest a longer, but more systematic solution using `IF`:

`=$B$9*$E$8*IF(A2=1;2;0,5)+$B$9*$E$9*IF(B2=1;2;0,5)`

This is a bit less general, but should produce the result you expect in this case.